# page authentication to specific pages

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-authentication

In my web site, I want to ask the users for permission to manage their pages.

I saw in the documentation that I need to use the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_ID&redirect_uri=MY_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
```

However, I retrieve back a list of pages which are manages by the user.

Is there a way that inside the auth dialog the user will see list of pages managed by him so he could confirm only those that he allows?

I also don't know what are the pages id, and prefer not to call a method where I need to specify the page id, but to get a token and page id from what he has already selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old authorization dialogs there was a drop-down so the user can specify which pages they want to allow.  However, that is now deprecated and the new dialog grants every page as you have found out.  Basically, your app can show the user which pages they currently have under their management (display list from data return for HTTP Get `/me/accounts`) and let them choose.

Comment: Thanks. However, what if I don't know what is the user id in facebook? It means that first I need to retrieve his token and then retrieve his pages?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Everything is explained here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I don't get something. is me in /me/accounts refers to the me (the developer) or to the client?

Comment: `/me` refers to the user to whom the token is assigned to.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I still do not get it. https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE returns only the token. How can I find out of it what is the id of the user to perform the /userid/accounts?

Comment: Call `\me` and see if there's a first_name property. If so, then it's a user, if not, then you can assume it's a page.

Comment: You said that \me should be replaced with the client id - so it should be \123456 (an example). However, I do I find out what is the client id 123456?

Comment: I'm thinking our communication is broken somewhat. Try calling /me in the graph API explorer with the token you get back and see for yourself the object.